# RubyGems 2.5.0 on Windows 7 SSL_connect certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby, ssl, bundler

Well, I ran `gem update --sytem` and now I appear to be hosed.

I'm trying to run a local Jekyll blog (to check my stuff I push it to github).

`jekyll serve` gives me:

```
c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect':     (Bundler::Dsl::DSLError)
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certific
ate verify failed. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from C:/Users/j6l/Documents/GitHubPages/johnl4.github.io/Gemfile:5
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  gem 'github-pages', versions['github-pages']
 >  gem 'jekyll-feed'
 #  source 'https://rubygems.org'
 #  -------------------------------------------
        from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
        from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
        from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
        from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
```

and some more stacktrace entries, but I think that's enough.

`bundle update` does the same think.

I am *not* a Ruby expert (nor a Jekyll one, for that matter), I just wanna get my blog out there.

I've looked at Luis Lavena's post about this issue for older versions of RubyGems, and he doesn't mention 2.5.0, which is brand spankin' new (just my luck, eh?).  Anyway, the cert .pem file in my ssl certs directory exactly matches what people say to download, so I'm not sure that's the problem, unless I'm looking in the wrong directory or something.

```
PS C:\Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\site_ruby\2.2.0\rubygems\ssl_certs> diff -ref $(get-content .\AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem) -dif $(get-content C:\Users\j6l\Downloads\AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem)
PS C:\Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\site_ruby\2.2.0\rubygems\ssl_certs>

PS C:\Users\j6l\Documents\GitHubPages\johnl4.github.io> gem update --system
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
PS C:\Users\j6l\Documents\GitHubPages\johnl4.github.io> ruby --version
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x64-mingw32]
PS C:\Users\j6l\Documents\GitHubPages\johnl4.github.io> gem --version
2.5.0
PS C:\Users\j6l\Documents\GitHubPages\johnl4.github.io> bundle --version
Bundler version 1.10.6
```

Now what?

(Thanks. :) )

Answer (score 0):

The possibilities are that you are getting a redirect or that you do have some sort of SSL incompatibility with rubygems.org.  When I look at these two gems I see this:

```
curl -I https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll-feed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 04 Nov 2015 19:23:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
ETag: W/"1585dca404914b49565650d7832c1c3f"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: _rubygems_session=UmJMc1NUeUoreGlUMHVxSWI1QVVJNXhVa1k2QXhqN1lEL09CTENFd2J4SUQ1RU5rdDZQU0h4eXhUVDcyeWoyUkdmQmpYRDFxY2tiUXI0YzFwMjBZRjNEWlNVaEZNTXJjcGJ2ekFkL0FRU1JNSkZxRnFVYlJJRUNxSlRsWUxRbW5rL3hIOE1zWWM0dUJqNDRKTTA2MFlnPT0tLUg1ODFvRFhRaDRqcXZjNjM4ZGg3S3c9PQ%3D%3D--61d9898027580b62e2c8b6f9a93bb719d5839dfc; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: fedceeef-2539-4942-838e-b8584e399109
X-Runtime: 0.036895
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1


curl -I https://rubygems.org/gems/github-pages
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 04 Nov 2015 19:23:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
ETag: W/"f3e79d7752d3eac43aee4f6786cc01ec"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: _rubygems_session=V0dhK0U1dWVyTDhZenVyUjUyUFlXbnc4clkzN2FCQk1wdlZHMkNWQWNPd1Z0REhWSmN0RmdwcDRtL0ZaQ2dEUGkwZUQrZEZBdHQ2VjY0UXN4Yk1idzlSQVRHSDgrc0xQZk5JLzJFV3N3c1BxcXdOOENXY2l1QWJsRUVzckdUTUw5NDQ0TU5JYWlRbmZEWkJPeEtzYXpRPT0tLXhhS1N2ZkJoYzZ1MTRZaTF1Nm45aFE9PQ%3D%3D--e912ea64a1b5c2ecf95524dddb704191b176f905; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: 9b8f3227-63cf-4c6b-9d63-aeb1b019a945
X-Runtime: 0.042007
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

what do you see using curl from the command line on the machine that you are trying to update?

Comment: I would have preferred to make this a comment rather than an answer as there is not enough information given in the question to establish what is likely the problem beyond that it has to do with https.  However, SO does not permit me to comment.  Thus the answer.  If you do not have curl on your windows box then you can get it here: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html [active as of 2015-11-04]

Comment: Interesting. PowerShell (3.0) has a built-in curl alias for Invoke-WebRequest, which, when run, gives me the same stuff you posted. Running the curl.exe (plain 64-bit, w/SSL) you pointed to gives me a cert failure, "unable to get local issuer certificate". When I specify `--cacert .\AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem` it works (and gives results similar to yours), but if I specify --capath $(pwd), it fails again.

Comment: Blog posts about this situation mention the possibility of fixing this problem by blowing away the gem sources cache, downloading the latest version of rubygems for windows and reinstalling.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Madmax, thanks for your help.  I wound up blowing away my entire Ruby install and the .gem directory in my home directory (which I wouldn't have known to look for, so thanks for that) and starting over (reinstalling ruby, rubygems, ruby dev kit, jekyll, etc.)  Since all I wanted was to get Jekyll working (with the jekyll-feed gem)....